# Unable to install WordPress plugins on Nginx

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I am trying to set up a WordPress website on a VPS using Nginx with the following specifications:

> CentOS 7
>   Nginx v1.12.2
>   PHP 7.2.2

The permissions and SELinux context of the html (Nginx root) folders and files:

> html root folder: 755 / httpd_sys_content_t
>   folders in html: 755 / httpd_sys_content_t
>   files in html: 644 / httpd_sys_content_t
>   wp-content folder: 755 / httpd_sys_rw_content_t
>   wp-content files: 644 /  httpd_sys_rw_content_t

Ownership:

> everything: root:nginx

However, I cannot install any plugins from the dashboard. Specifically, I am trying to install the [Thim Core](https://thimpresswp.github.io/thim-core/) plugin, and it is telling me that the plugin folder does not have the correct permissions. The next time I try to enter my wp-admin page, i get *Unable to connect* and the URL looks like this:

> http://MY-IP/wp-admin/?thim-auto-compile-sass-to-css

I have used a day trying to get somewhere without success, so I turn to you. I really hope someone can point me in the right direction here!

Update:
I am not sure this is relevant, but my wp-config.php is in another directory with the same permission and context as the 'html root folder', and the file itself with the same permission and context as the 'files in html'. Also, I am running SELinux in permissive mode without luck.

Comment: So, what are the ownership of the files and folders?

Comment: The user is root and the group is nginx for absolutely everything.

Comment: Then that's why it doesn't work.

Comment: I'd like to curse now, but that is probably not a good idea here. Changed to nginx:nginx and everything works. God, I swear I tried that before. Apparently, I did not. A thousand thanks to you, Michael.

Comment: Please enter as detailed an answer as you can in the answer box below, then 24 hours later mark it as answered. That stops others coming into the question trying to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help I received from Michael Hampton, I tried changing the ownership for all folders and files to:

> nginx:nginx

It now works perfectly.

The folder that contains the real wp-config.php file needs the same permission.